# Flot animating a vertical line from one point to other

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am stuck in a bit of a problem. You people might have seen an animated line which acts like a scanner in many apps. Well I ned something similar to that but I need it in a graph.

What I actually need is that I need to plt a vertical line which moves from one point to other automatically.

Let me give you a bit more explaination:
 1. I have a button
 2. I press the button and graph area appears.
 3. On the graph area, a vertical line scrolls through the area as if it is scanning the area.

I am able to plot the line but it is coming out to be a little tilted. The logic behind that is provided below:

```
for(i=0;i<frequencyArray.length;i++){
                 myTestArray2.push([i,outFrequencyArray[i]]);
            }

plot.setData([
              {data:myTestArray2,lines:{fill:false,lineWidth:3},shadowSize:10}
                    ]);

function setUpflot(){
            // setup plot

             //console.log("setUpflot");
             var options = {
                // series  : { shadowSize: 0, splines: {show:true,lineWidth:1}},
                 series  : { },

                 yaxis   : { ticks: 5, tickColor:"rgba(148,129,151,0.5)", min: minGraphY, max:maxGraphY,show: true},
                xaxis   : { tickLength:0,  show: false },
                grid    : { borderWidth:0,markings:[
                                {yaxis: { from: 200.0, to: 240.0 },color: "rgba(140,2,28,0.5)"}
                        ]}
             };
```

Comment: iDemon, the code you pasted seems to be incomplete precursor work to plotting a graph. I can't see anything that attempts to establish or animate your vertical "scanner-line".

Comment: thenx for my newNickname.... actually I have fixed it and shall be posting the answer shortly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put this together in response to a comment yesterday.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RUKvk/26/).

Produces:

[image]

```
plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
  [ { data: someData} ], {
  series: {
    lines: { show: true }
  },
  crosshair: { mode: "x" }, // turn crosshair on
  grid: { hoverable: true, autoHighlight: false },
  yaxis: { min: -1.2, max: 1.2 }
});

crossHairPos = plot.getAxes().xaxis.min;
direction = 1;

setCrossHair = function(){
   if (direction == 1){
     crossHairPos += 0.5;   
   }
   else
   {
       crossHairPos -= 0.5;
   }
   if (crossHairPos < plot.getAxes().xaxis.min){
       direction = 1;
       crossHairPos = plot.getAxes().xaxis.min;
   }
   else if (crossHairPos > plot.getAxes().xaxis.max)
   {
       direction = 0;
       crossHairPos = plot.getAxes().xaxis.max;
   }
  plot.setCrosshair({x: crossHairPos})
  setTimeout(setCrossHair,100);
}

// kick it off
setTimeout(setCrossHair,100);
```

Comment: Cool - crosshair plugin makes a lot of sense. Can be coded more concisely like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RUKvk/27/).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, nice.  I wrote that quickly and knew I wouldn't be winning any style points for my code ;)

Comment: Thanks Mark. For the record, there are no runtime advantages in my version - just more concise code. Some might say more readable, some might say less.

Comment: awesome job...i commented out the else part since i needed the scanner in one direction...although its something which I really wanted and wnated to implement, my purpose is already served by the answer which I have written. I will try yours as well and see the performance. I believe performance wise yours will be better since I  nee to plot a crosshair insted of a dataq array... I my case, I m plotting an infinite tan data array which results in a straight line to appear and scan the whole chart area.

Comment: if my question was something which would help others as well, kindly +1 it @Mark

Answer (score 1):

```
var frequencyIndex = 0; //dynamic values stored intialised with 0.
var outFrequencyArray = [];

for(i=0;i<totalPoints;i++){

              outFrequencyArray.push(minGraphY-1);
          } 


opd=Math.tan(Math.PI/2);
outFrequencyArray.splice(frequencyIndex,0,opd);
frequencyIndex++;
for(i=0;i<frequencyArray.length;i++){
myTestArray2.push([i,outFrequencyArray[i]]);
        }

plot.setData([
          {data:myTestArray2,lines:{fill:false,lineWidth:3},shadowSize:10}
                ]);

function setUpflot(){
        // setup plot

         //console.log("setUpflot");
         var options = {
            // series  : { shadowSize: 0, splines: {show:true,lineWidth:1}},
             series  : { },

             yaxis   : { ticks: 5, tickColor:"rgba(148,129,151,0.5)", min: minGraphY, max:maxGraphY,show: true},
            xaxis   : { tickLength:0,  show: false },
            grid    : { borderWidth:0,markings:[
                            {yaxis: { from: 200.0, to: 240.0 },color: "rgba(140,2,28,0.5)"}
                    ]}
         };
```

Comment: nice try but Mark's answer is quite straightforward.